# ANDROID View alignment on layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-relativelayout

I want to center the title "address" vertically within icon image, and i want to align the content "St. Lake 965" below the title, is there any way to do it?

[image: Layout example]

At the moment i have this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pin_point_seller"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pinpoint_icon"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_address_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="St. Lake 965"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But if i change the icon height the title "address" dont align vertically within icon

This is the result that i want:

[image: Example layout 2]

The icon was resized but the title stays centered vertically, and your content below stay the on same position

Comment: remove LinearLayout and in Textview address put android:layout_toRightof="@+id/pinpoint_icon" and android:layout_gravity="centerVerticle" in both image and textview address and in textview St. Lake 965 add android:layout_below="@id/pinpoint_icon"

Comment: @user3294034 I tried this, and the St. Lake 965 get below the icon, and i want to align below the address, by the left side

Comment: so make below the address and give this field the same attributes as you have given to the address

Comment: see below my answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont hardcode the height and width

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pin_point_seller" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pinpoint_icon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="St. Lake 965"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling the `ImageView` to the same height(that is defined by you) as the `textSize`+additional margin and paddings for the TextView that you want align with.

Comment: At the moment it was the best result, i wanted to do this dynamically but didn't found any way

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can dynamically set the textsize and scale ImageView in your activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layour instead of linear layout. Using following tags you can align the second textview jus below the first one

```
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
```

updated answer it may help you

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that i want the title stay centered vertically on icon, i edited the question and added image example of the target result

Answer (score 0):

Create a table layout like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pin_point_seller"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_address_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="St. Lake 965"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer hope it will help you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pin_point_seller"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinpoint_icon"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_address_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="St. Lake 965"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtAddress"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Give what height or width to the image you will not worry about both text